# Save Excel cell value of M/DD/YYYY as MMDDYYYY?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, string-formatting

Say I have a cell with the value 5/29/2013 as Text. When I click my form control "SAVE" button, I save that value into another worksheet cell (set the other worksheets cell value equal to the one with the date 5/29/2013).

How do I save (not format, save) 5/29/2013 as 05292013?

This gets exported to a .txt file and must be in format MMDDYYYY.

Answer (score 1):

`=TEXT(A1,"mmddyyyy")`

Sorry for the confusion; this will do what you're asking for.

Comment: Won't work. That sets the display format, but the actual value going to the .txt file is still MM/DD/YYYY.

Comment: @AnalyticLunatic I changed my answer. Hope this helps.

Comment: Not quite. Usually it would, but I need this operation to occur in VBA, not an Excel formula. I need to take Sheet1.Range("A1").value - (5/29/2013) and save as Sheet2.Range("A1").value - (05292013) for example. All my fields are set as Text currently, so this will work if it can be figured out. It's that, or I leave the DATE as (5/29/2013) and change it to (05292013) when saving into the .txt file, which I also don't know how to do :/

Comment: @AnalyticLunatic In that case, just use `date = Format(date,"mmddyyyy")` before inserting into Sheet2.

Comment: The following gives me a type mismatch error during execution: Worksheets("Export").range("L1:L" & rowCnt).value = Format(Worksheets("FeedSamples").range("M1:M" & rowCnt).value, "mmddyyyy"). Something obvious I'm missing here? I'm trying to straight "copy" certain columns of the first sheet into the second sheet for export to the .txt file.

Comment: @AnalyticLunatic You can't do the whole range at once like that. Create a loop like so: `For n = 1 To rowCnt
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("L" & n).Value = Format(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("M" & n).Value, "mmddyyyy")
    Next n`

Comment: I think I see what your saying (especially since I'm also copying the first row, or the columns "Headers"). You gave me the idea after copying everything to then format the column, but the following gives me "Subscript out of range" error: 
    For n = 2 To rowCnt
        Worksheets("Exoprt").range("L" & n).value = Format(Worksheets("Export").range("L" & n).value, "mmddyyyy")
    Next

Comment: Woops, spotted my goof! Had "Exoprt" instead of "Export". May have it now! :) Let me do some more testing real quick.